# How can I remove all instances of a certain value unless it is found to be part of quoted text?

Tags: javascript, regex, webkit

Using regular expressions, I want to remove all instances of a certain value unless the value is part of quoted text when it is found.

For example, if I want to remove the word *book* unless it is found in quotes, and I have the following text:

```
telephone book computer "i read a book" keyboard book
```

How can I use regular expressions to make it appear as:

```
telephone computer "i read a book" keyboard
```

Is this possible with WebKit JavaScript regex using string.replace?

Comment: How is Webkit JavaScript different from say Firefox JavaScript?

Comment: Specifically, I want this to work in WebKit. I'm not 100% sure about the details, but I keep reading that there are different regex engines in different software that all have varying levels of capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with help of a **callback** ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d8G44/)):

```
result = str.replace(/\bbook\b\s*|("[^"]*")/g, function(m, quotes){ return quotes ? quotes: '' });
```

Or with help of a **lookahead trick** like ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d8G44/1/)):

```
result = str.replace(/\bbook\b\s*(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)/g, '');
```

Last one only only works if quotes are always closed, and may not be efficient for long strings.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through and build the new string.  Keep track of whether the last quote you found was opening or closing.  Don't remove book if it is after an opening quote.